# How can we convert a current date to Julian date /day

Tags: sql, oracle

How can we format the current date into the Julian date?

And how can we format the current date into `HHMMSS` format without '.' 'S?

*For example:*

I should get the format as `:123022` not in `12.30.22`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can format the date with the `to_char` function and an mask.

For example to display HHMMSS use:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'HHMISS') from dual;
```

To see the Julian time use:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'J') from dual;
```

You can see more information about the mask here: [to_char function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)

Comment: @neha If the solution helped you then you should mark the question as answered. Please read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work